# Django:1045, "Access denied for user

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have already read a lot of stack overflow questions for two days, but I can't figure it out the problem(I am using Mac).

I did :  `mysql -u root -p`.

so it asked for the password, and root password is blank, no just an enter get me into mysql monitor and I received the message:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is xxx
Server version: 5.7.18 Homebrew
```

then:  `mysql> CREATE DATABASE concon CHARACTER SET utf8;`.

so: `mysql>CREATE USER 'concon'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';`.

finally: `mysql> GRANT ALL ON concon.* TO 'concon'@'localhost'`.

So I exit mysql and run `sudo python manage.py runserver`

the problem is I receive:  `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'concon'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")`

my dataBase is(in settings.py):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'concon',
        'USER': 'concon',
        'PASSWORD': 'thepassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

when I do : `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'concon'@'localhost';`
it shows:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for concon@localhost                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'concon'@'localhost'                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `concon`.* TO 'concon'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `cocoon != concon`

Answer (score 0):

try this command:
"mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
after you grant privileges to the user